# Is there a way to add a linebreak before any character in a set of characters in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

Is there a way to add a linebreak before any character in a set of characters in MS Word? I already had an answer for Notepad++, but I also need this feature (if possible) in Word.

E.g. I would like to add a linebreak before any number.

Before:

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 2 sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 3 Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 4 nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.
```

After:

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
2 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
3 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
4 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Find/Replace dialog box check Use Wildcards. If you replace single digits search for:

```
([0-9])
```

and replace with:

```
^p\1
```

If you replace numbers with one or more digit search for:

```
([0-9]{1;})
```

or

```
([0-9]{1,})
```

depending on your regional settings. Use the same "replace" as above.
In general (for a set of characters) put your characters between brackets, e.g. if you would like to add new line before 'a', 'f' or 'g' use:

```
([afg])
```

as a search pattern.